# how can be write php inside the laravel's blade page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

i write like this but did not got the output.

```
@php
  @if(isset($value['0']['cmsg'])) 
    $cmsg = json_decode($value['0']['cmsg']);
  @endif
  @if(isset($value['0']['cmsgerr'])) 
    $cmsgerr = json_decode($value['0']['cmsgerr']);
  @endif
@endphp
```

Comment: Blade is templating engine, it makes it easy for you to mix HTML with PHP commands. However you can use traditional PHP code in blade <?php //your commands ?>.

Comment: Also i don't see any output commands in your php code like echo, print, or even {}. You just have an assignments to $cmsg and $cmsgerr, so it will output nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `@php @endphp` you should use only php code, not blade code.

```
@php
  if(isset($value['0']['cmsg'])) {
    $cmsg = json_decode($value['0']['cmsg']);
  }

  if(isset($value['0']['cmsgerr'])) {
    $cmsgerr = json_decode($value['0']['cmsgerr']);
  }
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open php in laravel blade you can not use blade syntax in the PHP anymore. So your code should be like this :

```
@php
  if(isset($value['0']['cmsg'])) {
    $cmsg = json_decode($value['0']['cmsg']);
  }

  if(isset($value['0']['cmsgerr'])) {
    $cmsgerr = json_decode($value['0']['cmsgerr']);
  }
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you use @php blade directive that block will be recognized as a plain PHP block by blade compiler defined at `Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler` . So, anything you write inside the `@php .... @endphp` block should be the PHP code you want. There is no need to write other directives like @if, @foreach, etc within the @php block & that's wrong actually.
I hope you understand the idea & you can easily fix your code now.